# Draw straight line with two fingers

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics

How can I paint/draw a straight line with 2 fingers with the line being visible while the dragging or touching is still being done by the user? I've already tried simple painting using coregraphics but this one seems a bit complicated for me.

Comment: track touches in a touchesBegan, and touchesMoved. Draw them in a views DrawRect using CoreGraphics.

Comment: I can track the touches now in my view, questions is with 2 fingers how do I detect the current position (x and y) of the other finger? Since I need to get both the x and y of the 1st and 2nd fingers to identify where to draw the line.

Comment: @jeraldov: Each touch corresponds to a finger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Justin's point, just handle `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved`.

Thus, if you subclass `UIView`, the CoreGraphics implementation might look like:

```
@interface CustomView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *paths;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBezierPath *currentPath;

@end

@implementation CustomView

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.currentPath)
    {
        if (!self.paths)
            self.paths = [NSMutableArray array];

        self.currentPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        self.currentPath.lineWidth = 3.0;

        [self.paths addObject:self.currentPath];

        [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([touches count] != 2)
        return;

    [self.currentPath removeAllPoints];

    __block NSInteger i = 0;
    [touches enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UITouch *touch, BOOL *stop) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];

        if (i++ == 0)
            [self.currentPath moveToPoint:location];
        else
            [self.currentPath addLineToPoint:location];
    }];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.currentPath = nil;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];

    for (UIBezierPath *path in self.paths)
    {
        [path stroke];
    }
}

- (void)reset
{
    self.paths = nil;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

Alternatively, you can also use Quartz 2D and define your own `CAShapeLayer` objects, and then either your view subclass or your view controller could do something like (needless to say, this is the view controller implementation; the view implementation should be obvious):

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) CAShapeLayer *currentLayer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBezierPath *currentPath;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.currentLayer)
    {
        CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        layer.lineWidth = 3.0;
        layer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
        layer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
        self.currentLayer = layer;

        self.currentPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

        [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([touches count] != 2)
        return;

    [self.currentPath removeAllPoints];

    __block NSInteger i = 0;
    [touches enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UITouch *touch, BOOL *stop) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        if (i++ == 0)
            [self.currentPath moveToPoint:location];
        else
            [self.currentPath addLineToPoint:location];
    }];

    self.currentLayer.path = [self.currentPath CGPath];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.currentPath = nil;
    self.currentLayer = nil;
}

- (IBAction)didTouchUpInsideClearButton:(id)sender
{
    for (NSInteger i = [self.view.layer.sublayers count] - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if ([self.view.layer.sublayers[i] isKindOfClass:[CAShapeLayer class]])
            [self.view.layer.sublayers[i] removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
}

@end
```

For this latter approach, you need to [add the QuartzCore.framework to your project](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html).